# Unable to reach/access port 8080 on Ubuntu server (Traefik)

Tags: docker, port, traefik

I set up Traefik's dashboard on port 8080 with Docker but I'm only able to access it on the host.

1. `ufw`, `iptables`, and `firewalld` are not enabled.
2. `nmap` shows

   ```
   $ nmap -p 8080 localhost
   Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-02-04 01:51 UTC
   Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
   Host is up (0.0029s latency).
   PORT     STATE SERVICE
   8080/tcp open  http-proxy`
   ```

   Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
3. `curl` shows

   ```
   $ curl localhost:8080
   <a href="/dashboard/">Found</a>

   $ curl xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080
   <a href="/dashboard/">Found</a>.
   ```
4. `netstat` shows

   ```
   $ netstat -vatn
   Active Internet connections (servers and established)
   Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
   tcp6       0      0 :::2376                 :::*                    LISTEN
   tcp6       0      0 :::2377                 :::*                    LISTEN
   tcp6       0      0 :::7946                 :::*                    LISTEN
   tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
   tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
   tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
   tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
   tcp6       0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:2377     xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:55446   ESTABLISHED
   ```

Here's the attempt in trying to access the server on port 8080 that just shows timeout.

[reaching through browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8BLa.jpg)

Here's trying to curl it from a different machine

```
$ curl xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx port 8080: Timed out
```

I'm able to reach it on port `80` (there's an empty nginx redirecting server behind Traefik)

```
$ curl xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.13.8</center>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Including TOML as requested

```
accessLogsFile = "/dev/stdout"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
      CertFile = "/run/secrets/cert.pem"
      KeyFile = "/run/secrets/key.pem"

[web]
address = ":8080"

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "localhost"
watch = true
swarmmode = true
exposedbydefault = false
```

Comment: Could you share your config.toml?

Comment: okay just added it

Comment: How are you running traefik? As a docker container?

Comment: running it as a service using `docker stack deploy`

Comment: Same problem here. Did you come up with a solution?